# How to add credit card using Braintree Hosted Fields with 3D Secure verification

Tags: payment, braintree, 3d-secure

I have a credit card addition as a separate step in the flow. That means I'm creating credit cards via Braintree Hosted Fields without running a transaction. To use vaulted credit cards for future transactions.

As I understand it right (correct me if I'm wrong), I can and should verify credit cards on their creation by running 3d Secure verification.

There are two things I'm not sure about:

1. Should I even run 3d Secure verification when adding a credit card?
2. If yes, what should be passed in the threeDSecureParams.amount (cause eventually, the amount is set between $0 and $1 by the 3D Secure processor)?

```
threeDSecureParams = {
    cardAddChallengeRequested: true,
    bin: tokenizeData.details.bin,
    email: email,
    nonce: tokenizeData.nonce,
    amount: 1
}
```

P.S. As I didn't find a clear answer in the Braintree doc and by googling, while I'm waiting for Braintree support to get a reply on this, I've decided to see how you guys managed to set such flow.

I really appreciate any help/opinion.

Comment: I've created an issue on that (not just this): https://github.com/braintree/braintree-android-drop-in/issues/376 because we don't get any satisfied response from Braintree support or documentation.